# how to hide file without change attributes?

Tags: c++, attributes, hide

I'm trying to figure out how the program "Easy File Locker" hide or make it not readable or writable without changing any file attributes. I used GetFileAttributes() to check and any attributes really change. Someone know which way it uses to hide file ?

Comment: `GetFileAttrubites()` is not standard C++. What compiler and what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 on windows 10. 
including #include <Windows.h> to it